# Show data based on number of appearances MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, count

I am trying to list the top 3 names that appear most often in my MySql Database.

This is what I'm using to do:

```
        $nameQuery = "SELECT PeopleName, COUNT(*) AS totalNumber FROM finaldb ORDER BY        COUNT(PeopleName) LIMIT 5";
        $nameResult = mysql_query($nameQuery);
        while($data = mysql_fetch_array($nameResult)) {

              $name = $data['totalNumber'];
        }

 echo $name;
```

However, that doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

My DB consists of: PeopleName, ID and is called finaldb.

Comment: *Obligatory:* The `mysql_*` functions is [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: If it doesn't seem to work - what does it do? Crash? Give an error message? Return the wrong data? Return the right data, but not all of it?

Comment: @andrewsi Just doesn't return anything.

Comment: @user2544712 - Is the problem that the PHP code is failing, or that the query doesn't work?

Comment: I don't think the PHP code to return it is properly written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return 1 result with that query, but that's it. You need to add a GROUP BY clause to your SQL:

```
SELECT PeopleName, COUNT(PeopleName) AS totalNumber FROM finaldb GROUP BY PeopleName ORDER BY COUNT(PeopleName) DESC LIMIT 5
```

You can also check what your query should return by running it on the mysql command line or inside of phpmyadmin.

Your loop is only assigning the latest totalNumber to $name. If you want to echo all of the data, try this:

```
    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($nameResult)) {

          echo "{$data['PeopleName']} - {$data['totalNumber']}\n";
    }
```

For adding data, just keep adding column names:

```
          echo "{$data['PeopleName']} - {$data['totalNumber']} - {$data['Gender']} - {$data['Age']}\n";
```

Comment: that returns a physical number count but not the data itself.

Comment: What is it returning, and what are you looking for?  It should return something like  `John  10  James 8  Robert 7`

Comment: Of course, you're only assigning the totalNumber to $name, so when you echo $name, you're only going to get the last totalNumber from your loop.

Comment: What would I do instead?

Comment: That works now. What would I do if I wanted to base it off the name and what gender was selected for that name if I had a Gender option. So basing the selection of two values. Most popular for boy, most popular for girl.

Comment: You would add more options, and make sure to add it to the GROUP BY. So you would change GROUP BY to `GROUP BY PeopleName,Gender,Age` etc and so on.

Comment: And how would I print it then? Say Gender has two options, Boy or Girl. How do I make it so I'm grouping by when it's a boy?

Comment: The Group By clause already divides it up. You just need to add the columns into the echo line.

Comment: How would i go about doing that? I would really appreciate it if you updated your answer with an example. I come from a mobile dev background.

Comment: Done. I'd really recommend reading up on arrays and how to use them.

Comment: Yeah, I actually figured it out around an hour ago. Thanks for the answers though!

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the Group By, try this query:

```
$nameQuery = "SELECT PeopleName, COUNT(PeopleName) AS totalNumber FROM finaldb GROUP BY PeopleName ORDER BY        COUNT(PeopleName) LIMIT 5";
```

Comment: that returns a physical number count but not the data itself

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    PeopleName
    count(PeopleName)
FROM
    finalDB
GROUP BY 
    PeopleName
ORDER BY
    count(PeopleName) DESC
LIMIT 0,3
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loop isn't preserving the names you pull out, it simply overrites the PREVIOUS name with the next value. You need to build an array of values, or at least do your output inside the loop. e.g.

```
$names = array();
while(...) {
   $names[] = array('name' => $data['PeopleName'], 'total' => $data['totalNumber']);
}
var_dump($names);
```